# Find index of Lines in which we have special Regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a String, which consists of a number of emails, i want to find index of lines that contain emails. i've tried the following codes, it just returns emails.

```
str = '''purple alice@google.com
         blah blah
         blah blah
         blah monkey bob@abc.com blah dishwasher
'''

  emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', str)
```

the result of this code is `['alice@google.com', 'bob@abc.com']`, but i need to find the indices of lines that contain these emails, my desired output is `[0,3]`. i know i can search for the found emails in the `str` and find the lines, but i think it is not efficient. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Match objects do not contain line number details. You will have to split the text into lines and keep track of their IDs while matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that's tricky and effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate each line to get the line index.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = '''purple alice@google.com
         blah blah
         blah blah
         blah monkey bob@abc.com blah dishwasher
'''

idx = [i for i, line in enumerate(s.splitlines()) if re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)]
print(idx)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 3]
```